# Error: Could not find or load main class bankapplication.mainmenu

Tags: java

Can someone please tell me the error? I am new to Java.

```
package bankapplication;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainmenu {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void main() {
        createanaccount accountObject = new createanaccount();
        viewaccount viewObject = new viewaccount();

        System.out.println("Select an option");

        System.out.println("1\t Create an account");
        System.out.println("2\t View an account");
        System.out.println("3\t Quit");
        int option = in.nextInt();

        switch (option) {
            case 1: accountObject.createanaccount() ; {
            }

            case 2: viewObject.viewaccount() ;{
            }

            case 3: System.exit(3); {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code... - Besides that, the signature for `main()` is wrong. It needs to be `public void main(String[] args)` or `public void main(String... args)` (which practially is the same).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: the main has also to be static AFAIK

Comment: @Thomas Well, both suggestions are wrong :P. Like RC. already wrote: `main` is a `static` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Salman what Icould figure out of your code was your main body shoul look some what like this :

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

}
```

And I think you need import statements for createanaccount and viewanaccount class

Comment: Try coding using eclipsce if you are a beginner in java .It really helps with the syntax.